# Best way to plot a graph with a Function that returns 3 values

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I have a function:

```
def tacoma(dt=1, cromer=True):

    ..........
    ..........

    return times, theta, displacement
```

That returns 3 arrays of time, theta  and y. What I would like to do is plot two graphs, one showing how theta varies with times, and the other how displacement varies with times, (the length of all of the arrays is the same).

I do not now how to best do this, is there a way I can access times, theta, displacement individually when I call a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign your function's output to variables and use them with `matplotlib`.

Here is a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def tacoma(dt=1, cromer=True):
    # this is just a dummy example
    times = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
    theta = np.sin(times)
    displacement = times**2-dt*times+1
    return times, theta, displacement

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
times, th, dis = tacoma()
ax1.plot(times, th)
ax2.plot(times, dis)

ax1.set_title('theta')
ax2.set_title('displacement')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, how do I then add axes titles?